# Does Youtube API have "AND and OR" search and explicit match search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api

Does Youtube API allow me to do searches like

```
Search videos which have (in their title) strings both Lady Gaga AND (Cyrus OR Muse)
```

And does Youtube API allow me to do searches like

```
Search videos which have (in their title) string exactly Katy Perry. I don't want titles which have Katy Elizabeth Perry.
```

What's the most efficient code to write that type of search request? I want to code it using Ruby on rails.

I've gone through various introduction about how to search Youtube but they were mainly talking about other filtering things like relevance and view counts filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And is supported with include and exclude just like the search query in the Web UI.

You can use -{query term} to exclude a query term. Or |{gaga} to OR.

like {lady -gaga} or in decoded form

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=lady+-gaga&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can also make separate calls, put results into sets and do all these operations in your client.

Comment: @lbrahim_Ulukaya Thank you. But if I make separate calls (say 3 separate calls), then perhaps that will consume triple times more time, right?

Comment: You can make async calls. They don't need to be dependent on each other.

Comment: @lbrahim_Ulukaya What is async call? Is that something that allows me to perform "OR" search in Youtube API somewhat "indirectly"? If I do that, can I do OR search as fast as if there is direct "OR" search in Youtube API?

Comment: It's not about YouTube. When you can have separate threads for each call from your client. What you wanted to do is all about your own implementation, not about YT API.

Comment: @lbrahim_Ulukaya But https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters    This says that "Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms." But you said "Only AND is supported via API, just like the search query in the Web UI." I am confused. Can both be correct? Was there version change of Youtube API?

Comment: You are right, same query parameters are supported in v3 too but was not documented. Will get it documented, thanks